# How to Unit Test Cache Control header using JUnit?

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, junit4

I just created a CacheControl to use on the response from REST services, it is a ResponseBuilder which takes a ResponseBuilder as parameter on which i set the no cache options. The code is shown below.

```
        /**
 * Cacheless method to control the Cache Header in REST responses.
 * @param builder the response builder
 * @return Cache Control Header for REST Responses
 */
private ResponseBuilder setCacheControlHeader(final ResponseBuilder builder) {
    CacheControl control = new CacheControl();
    control.setNoCache(true);
    control.setNoStore(true);
    control.setMaxAge(0);
    control.setPrivate(true);
    control.setMustRevalidate(true);
    control.setNoTransform(true);
    builder.cacheControl(control);
    builder.header("Pragma", "no-cache");
    builder.header("Expires", 0);

    return builder;
}
```

As I am just working on on the methods I am using PostMan to test the headers which seems to be fine. 
Now I am trying to create a JUnit test to test if the Response builder passed on to the method is getting assigned the parameters on the method such as "noCache, "noStore" and "expires".

I would need to test it for each of my RestServices which is using this method.
Can someone suggest how to test it?

Regards

Comment: In the end, the desired thing should be some response headers, correct? In this case, I would simply use Rest-Assured ( https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured ) to test the headers that you get when calling the service. Would be an integration test, of course.

Comment: Thank you. having a look at it now, looks the way to go. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using RestAssured, it is as simple as:

```
    given().param("bookId", book.getId())
           .get("/api/books/")
           .then()
           .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK)
           .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
```